# add new item with existing item in listview C#

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

There are some items already present in my listView . There is an add button on the page that opens an dialog where user can add a new item. Once the dialog closes I have to append that new item with already existing item. Here is the code  and it goes till end but the new item is not added. i have multiple columns in my list view.What i am doing wrong in this.

```
public frmEditObject(AddException ObjException)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    if (ObjException != null)
    {
        ListViewItem lviMember, lviSender = null;
        bool alreadyExists =
            exceptionsList.Find(
                item =>
                item.UserDetail == ObjException.UserDetail && item.ExceptionType != ObjException.ExceptionType) !=
            null
                ? true
                : false;
        if (!alreadyExists)
        {
            exceptionsList.Add(ObjException);
            lvwExceptionMember.Items.Clear();
            lvwExceptionMember.BeginUpdate();
            foreach (var item in exceptionsList)
            {
                if (item.ExceptionType == Enumerations.ExceptionType.Members)
                {
                    lviMember = new ListViewItem(
                        item.UserDetail);
                    lviMember.Tag = 0;
                    lviMember.SubItems.Add(GetDisplayNameFromSamAccountName(item.UserDetail));

                    lvwExceptionMember.Items.Add(lviMember);

                }
            }
            lvwExceptionMember.EndUpdate();
            lvwExceptionMember.Refresh();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You just want to add new AddException object to listview, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these steps:

```
public frmEditObject(AddException ObjException)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //CHECK THAT YOUR OBJECT IS ALIVE
    if (ObjException != null)
    {
        ListViewItem lviMember, lviSender = null;
        bool alreadyExists = exceptionsList.Find(item => item.UserDetail == ObjException.UserDetail && item.ExceptionType != ObjException.ExceptionType) != null ? true : false;
        if (!alreadyExists)
        {
             //CHECK THAT NEW ITEM IS REALLY NEW, DOES NOT EXIST IN LIST
             exceptionsList.Add(ObjException);

             //YOU DO NOT NEED TO CLEAR LIST AND ADD ALL ITEMS TO IT
             //lvwExceptionMember.Items.Clear();


             //lvwExceptionMember.BeginUpdate();

                 Debug.WriteLine(item.ExceptionType);                 
                 if (item.ExceptionType == Enumerations.ExceptionType.Members)
                 {
                      //CHECK DOES YOUR OBJECT HAVE MEMBERS TYPE
                      lviMember = new ListViewItem(item.UserDetail);
                      lviMember.Tag = 0;
                      lviMember.SubItems.Add(GetDisplayNameFromSamAccountName(item.UserDetail));

                      lvwExceptionMember.Items.Add(lviMember);

                 }

            // lvwExceptionMember.EndUpdate();
            //lvwExceptionMember.Refresh();
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: When you start app in debug mode, set breakpoint at the line where you add item to lvwExceptionMember, does application break execution on that line?

Comment: Well, then there are two possible reasons: 1. new item already exists in list, 2. new item does not have ExceptionType == Members

Comment: the new item is not in the list and exception item is of type members

Comment: Can you check via debugger does it new item and item is type of members. If everything is ok, app need to break at break point (if you set one at line lvwExceptionMember.Items.Add(lviMember);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17800/discussion-between-danilo-vulovic-and-ankur)

Comment: I have found the culprit and it is working fine now. The reason for item not able to be added was I was calling the constructor of the form and the items were getting refreshed. changed that thing on button click.